# Test component with subscription in ngOnInit - Angular 11

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm new to testing in Jasmine and Karma and I'm trying to figure out how to test the observable of a component which gets set in the ngOnInit.

I have the following component:

```
export class Component implements OnInit{
    
    currentConfig$: Observable<Config>;
    
    constructor(
         private someService: someService,
         private route: ActivatedRoute
    ){}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
            this.someService.init(params.name)
        })
        this.currentConfig = this.someService.config$
    }

}
```

Here's the service:

```
export class SomeService {

    private subject: Subject<Config> = new Subject()
    
    readonly config$ = subject.asObservable()

    init(name: string): void {
        this.findOne(name).subscribe(res => {
            if (res)
                this.subject.next({name})
        })
        
    }

    findOne(name): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.get('api');
    }

}
```

And then I can subscribe to the currentConfig observable with the async pipe in the template.
I'm trying to test the values emitted by `currentConfig$` of the Component.

Here's what my test looks like now:

```
fit('should show create component', fakeAsync(() => {
    const component = fixture.componentInstance;
    const debugElement = fixture.debugElement;
    const expected = {name: 'ok'}

    // this works
    someService.config$.subscribe(config => console.log(config));
    
    // this doesn't work even if I put it after the detect changes
    // component.currentConfig$.subscribe(config => console.log(config));

    spyOn(someService, 'findOne').and.returnValue(of(expected));
    fixture.detectChanges(); 

}));
```

The component `currentConfig$` is undefined if I try to subscribe to it. Could it be because of the async pipe which consumes the value emitted? Or I'm totally in the wrong direction? And how could I test it then?

I'm also still pretty confused about the spyOn. Should spy on a function of the service that deep inside of the ngOnInit?

**EDIT**

I think I solved it. I had to call `component.ngOnInit()` instead of `fixture.detectChanges()`, then subscribe to the component observable and then call `fixture.detectChanges()`.

Here's the final test working:

```
fit('should get room config given room name', fakeAsync(() => {
    const component = fixture.componentInstance;

    const config: Config= {
        name: 'name',
    };
    // mock service response
    spyOn(roomService, 'findOne').and.returnValue(of(response));
    // call ngOnInit instead. Detect changes keeps observable cold.
    component.ngOnInit();

    component.roomConfig$.subscribe(config => expect(config).toEqual(roomConfig));
    
    // trigger second change detection.
    fixture.detectChanges();

}));
```

I'm not sure why detectChanges kept the observable cold. If anyone can clear that out?

Answer (score 1):

ngOnInit is called during first change detection. in your test you could try to call it manually `component.ngOnInit()` or, in case if you want to run it in a more like runtime environment - by calling the change detection itself `fixture.detectChanges()`

Comment: I think I already do that? Last line of the test

Comment: just run change detection before you are refering to currentConfig$, not after it

Comment: It doesn't work. As I said in the comments of the test, if I place it after the change detection it's still undefined

Comment: do you see any errors with detectChanges before subscribtion?

Comment: No, but nothing is emitted from the observable. The console.log prints null

Comment: here you are making the observable to error `and.returnValue(throwError({status: 404}));`. why would there be any events inside of config$? as I look through code errors reach nowhere

Comment: I think I just copied the wrong line, edited.

Comment: and what is `route.params` value? is it `{}` - empty object?

Comment: No it's not. I provided a value in the test

Comment: could you also provide route configuration from tests?